# How can I create an automatic calorie counter in excel with a reference database?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, automation

I have a small database of nutritional facts of the foods I eat on a daily basis.

Right now, to calculate daily intake, I put the information in individually for each unit of food consumed. I'm wondering if there is a way to automate this process as its a bit tedious.

For example - I have the calories, protein and fats data on the far right of my sheet, and I'd like to enter "Scrambled Eggs" in one cell, with the cell next to it having the quantity and have it populate the nutritional facts based on quantity.

Is there a way to do this? If further clarification is needed, please let me know.

Comment: The typical way to do that is to have a lookup table with the foods and the values.  Use one of the lookup functions (usually VLOOKUP or INDEX + MATCH) to retrieve the values where needed based on the food name in the data.  Use the quantity to calculate the result with the retrieved value in the destination cell.  Examples and tutorials are widely available online.  Give it a try and post back if you have a specific problem or question.

Comment: @ReyJuna That comment was meant for a different question...not sure how it wound up here.  my error!

Answer (score 0):

I am taking Food as A, B, C, D, E.

Each Food has different amounts of Calories, Proteins and Fats, as per the DATA TABLE - I

As you change the number of units of the foods, Calories, Proteins and Fats amount will change. Total will change. Decide the right quantities of foods to arrive at the requirement.

Comment: I have sent you two tables along with the formulae, but I wonder not displayed here. So again I will send you the Food Data Table, Food Values Table along with the formulae.

Comment: Food Calories Protein Fats  Food Units Calories Protein Fats 
A 50 10 40  A 4 200 40 160 
B 80 20 15  B 1 80 20 15 
C 60 30 25  C 2 120 60 50 
D 45 50 10  D 3 135 150 30 
E 70 30 20  E 1 70 30 20 
          
 DATA TABLE - I  ( Above )    TOTAL 605 300 275 
          

         


          
          
          
          
          
          
          
          
          
 Formulae used in calculations : TABBLE - 2  ( Above )

Comment: Food Calories Protein Fats
A 50 10 40
B 80 20 15
C 60 30 25
D 45 50 10
E 70 30 20
   
 DATA TABLE - I   

Food Units Calories Protein Fats
A 4 =VLOOKUP(F2,$A$2:$D$6,2)*G2 =VLOOKUP(F2,$A$2:$D$6,3)*G2 =VLOOKUP(F2,$A$2:$D$6,4)*G2
B 1 =VLOOKUP(F3,$A$2:$D$6,2)*G3 =VLOOKUP(F3,$A$2:$D$6,3)*G3 =VLOOKUP(F3,$A$2:$D$6,4)*G3
C 2 =VLOOKUP(F4,$A$2:$D$6,2)*G4 =VLOOKUP(F4,$A$2:$D$6,3)*G4 =VLOOKUP(F4,$A$2:$D$6,4)*G4
D 3 =VLOOKUP(F5,$A$2:$D$6,2)*G5 =VLOOKUP(F5,$A$2:$D$6,3)*G5 =VLOOKUP(F5,$A$2:$D$6,4)*G5
E 1 =VLOOKUP(F6,$A$2:$D$6,2)*G6 =VLOOKUP(F6,$A$2:$D$6,3)*G6 =VLOOKUP(F6,$A$2:$D$6,4)*G6

Comment: TOTAL =SUM(H2:H7) =SUM(I2:I7) =SUM(J2:J7)